# Images get spoiled after rotation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, autorotate

I have a UIYableView and I keep images in that tableview, I change the UIImageView size each time I rotate the phone. I check the self.interfaceOrientation in the tableView:cell:forIndexpath and decide what sizes to give to the imageview.And I off cource reload the tableview each time rotation occurs. But after rotation the images seem to get mixed. I mean I get a part of an image on another image.What would be the best approach to fix this?

Edit:Added some code

In tableview:cell:forIndexPath method I do the following:

```
...............
NSUIinteger row=indexPath.row;
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIIMage alloc]initWithImage:[images ojectAtIndex:row]];
if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
 imageView.Frame.Size=CGSizeMake(320.0,460.0);    
else
 imageView.Frame.Size=CGSizeMake(480.0,300.0);
imageView.contentMode=UIContentModeAspectFit;
[cell.contentView addSubView:imageView];
```

in the tableview:height:forIndexPath method:

```
double height;
if(self.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
 height=460;    
else
 height=300;  
return height;
```

I return the width of the row the same way.

Comment: You need to show some code for us to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you doing any drawing (UIKit) calls on background threads? That's the most common cause of this kind of drawing corruption.

Next, why are you doing a `reloadData` after rotation? That shouldn't be necessary if you're just resizing things. What kinds of images are these? Autoresizing will generally do what you want, and if not, you can re-layout the cells without reloading them.

I strongly suspect background operations here, but if not, then I would suspect that your `cellForIndexPath:` is not returning valid cells after rotation, probably an issue with how you set the imageView.

Comment: I do not use any drawing. I reload data to get the cell:forIndexpath method executed again as I change the imageview sizes everytime.

Comment: Do you do anything at all on background threads related to UIKit? Adding or removing views, messing with UIImageViews, etc. It's not just drawRect: that isn't thread safe.

Comment: My point about changing the imagesizes is that you shouldn't have to generate completely new cells for that. Your cells can resize themselves. Autoresize often does fine, but you can also use `layoutSubviews` in your UITableViewCell to rearrange itself. See this question for a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822946/auto-resizing-uitableview-on-rotation-with-flexible-width